# How to reset to a different stack with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

We are using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) as the default navigation system in our react native app, which currently has multiple stacks. We would like to navigate from a screen in one stack to a screen in another stack. This is a basic example of the different stacks:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: connectToStore(SplashScreen),
},{
  initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
  mode: 'card'
})

const ModalNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: connectToStore(LoginScreen),
})

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  StackNavigator: StackNavigator,
  ModalNavigator: ModalNavigator,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'StackNavigator',
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal'
})
```

The problem is if we try to reset to a new screen like so:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'LoginScreen',
    })
  ]
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

We get an error that says something like so:

> ExceptionsManager.js:74 Error: There is no route defined for key
>   DashboardScreen. Must be one of: 'StackNavigator','ModalNavigator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question doesn't seem well documented or answered other places here it is

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'ModalNavigator',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName:'LoginScreen', 
        params:{}
      })
    })
  ]
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

First we need to specify the correct stack we want to `resetTo` in this case the `ModalNavigator` and then we add a sub-action where we can specify the screen of that navigator ie `LoginScreen`.

And just for future reference, to pop or go back we can use

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop({ n:1 }));
```

where n is the number of screens to pop, or just to go all the way:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

Comment: I'm still unable to specify an action from another stack, it give me an error and says must be one of the key from my current stack.

Comment: Where to add Sub Actions ?